# Conditional sql WHERE clause based on column values

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores users. Every user has an `ID`, a `Name` and an `Access Level`. The three possible `Access Levels` are `Administrator`, `Manager` and `Simple User`.

What I want is to conditionally select from this table based on the `Access Level` value. I demonstrate the logic bellow:

1. If user is `Administrator`, then select all users (`Administrators, Managers, Simple Users`)
2. Else if user is `Manager` select all `Managers` and all `Simple Users`
3. Else if user is `Simple User` select only himself

Is that possible?

Comment: Are the access levels all stored as strings, or are they numbers (foreign keys)?

Comment: They are numbers. Foreign keys to the Access_Levels table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing Access Level is an integer that increases with the actual access level:
Administrator = 3
Manager = 2
User = 1

Then

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE ACCESS_LEVEL <= (SELECT ACCESS_LEVEL FROM USERS WHERE ID = @ID)
```

And just switch the less than sign to greater than if it is opposite.

Applies to SQL-server

EDIT: To get what you want you can use something like this:

```
SELECT id,name FROM users where ID = @id
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT id, name from users where access_level <= 
    (select case when access_level = 1 then 0 else access_level end
    from users where id = @id)
```

With a query like this you will select all users at your current access_level or lower.
Only exception if your access_level is 1 (e.g. normal user), then only your own user is selected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i didn't make myself clear. Sorry just first post here. What i want i something like: SELECT id,name FROM users WHERE access_level <= (select access_level from users WHERE id=@id) AND {IF access_level = Administrator id = *} {ELSE IF access_level = Manager id = *} {ELSE IF access_level = Simple User id=(SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = @id)}

Comment: The Only problem with the above logic is that a "Simple User" can see all other Simple users

Comment: You can make user829237 solution work in MySQL by replacing `end case` with `end`. Example: `SET @id = 200;
SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE ID = @id
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE access_level <=
(
 SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN access_level = 1
      THEN 0
      ELSE access_level
    END
 FROM users
 WHERE id = @id
)`

Answer (score 1):

In `Oracle` the concept is known as **Row Level Security**. See articles such as [this](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/oracle-row-level-security-part-1) or [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/restricting_access.htm) to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code

```
If(access_level=='administrator'){   str query = 'select * from users';}else if(access_level=='manager'){    str query = 'select * from users where  access_level!="administrator"'; }else{   str query = 'select * from users where access_level="users"'; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately i'm using a Joomla component that doesn't allow me to use php logic. I have to do it in the select statement

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little overkill, but the following stored procedure can be used to achieve what you want:

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `listAccessibleUsers`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `listAccessibleUsers`(IN user_id INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE u_access_level INT;

  -- Select the user access level  
  SELECT access_level 
  FROM users
  WHERE users.id = user_id
  INTO u_access_level;

  -- Result for simple users
  IF u_access_level = 1 THEN
    SELECT id, name, access_level 
    FROM users
    WHERE users.id = user_id;
  -- Result for admistrators and managers
  ELSE
    SELECT id, name, access_level  
    FROM users
    WHERE access_level <= u_access_level;  
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Example calling code:

```
CALL listAccessibleUsers(200);
```